# Display multiple table in DatagridView using vb.net and Ms Access

Tags: vb.net, ms-access-2010

Hello guys I'm having a problem with this one. I want to get the value of my 5 table in Ms Access DB and put it to a single DatagridView.. Here's my code .. I get the value in my table and I want it to display in DataGridView.. 
Thanks in advance.

'code

```
        If cmbGradelevel.Text = "All" Then
        Dim da As New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT Number_001 as [Number],StudentID_001 as [Student Number], " & _
                                           "LastName_001 as [Last Name],FirstName_001 as [First Name], " & _
                                           " MiddleName_001 as [Middle Name], Address_001 as [Address], " & _
                                           "Age_001 as [Age], Gender_001 as [Gender]" & _
                                           " FROM grade1 ORDER BY Number_001", con)

        con.Close()

        '
        Dim da2 As New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT Number_002 as [Number],StudentID_002 as [Student Number], " & _
                                 "LastName_002 as [Last Name],FirstName_002 as [First Name], " & _
                                 " MiddleName_002 as [Middle Name], Address_002 as [Address], " & _
                                 "Age_002 as [Age], Gender_002 as [Gender]" & _
                                 " FROM grade2 ORDER BY Number_002", con)

        con.Close()
        '
        Dim da3 As New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT Number_003 as [Number],StudentID_003 as [Student Number], " & _
                                 "LastName_003 as [Last Name],FirstName_003 as [First Name], " & _
                                 " MiddleName_003 as [Middle Name], Address_003 as [Address], " & _
                                 "Age_003 as [Age], Gender_003 as [Gender]" & _
                                 " FROM grade3 ORDER BY Number_003", con)
        con.Close()
        '

        Dim da4 As New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT Number_004 as [Number],StudentID_004 as [Student Number], " & _
                                 "LastName_004 as [Last Name],FirstName_004 as [First Name], " & _
                                 " MiddleName_004 as [Middle Name], Address_004 as [Address], " & _
                                 "Age_004 as [Age], Gender_004 as [Gender]" & _
                                 " FROM grade4 ORDER BY Number_004", con)
        con.Close()
        '
        Dim da5 As New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT Number_005 as [Number],StudentID_005 as [Student Number], " & _
                                            "LastName_005 as [Last Name],FirstName_005 as [First Name], " & _
                                            " MiddleName_005 as [Middle Name], Address_005 as [Address], " & _
                                            "Age_005 as [Age], Gender_005 as [Gender]" & _
                                            " FROM grade5 ORDER BY Number_005", con)
        con.Close()
        '
        Dim da6 As New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT Number_006 as [Number],StudentID_006 as [Student Number], " & _
                                 "LastName_006 as [Last Name],FirstName_006 as [First Name], " & _
                                 " MiddleName_006 as [Middle Name], Address_006 as [Address], " & _
                                 "Age_006 as [Age], Gender_006 as [Gender]" & _
                                 " FROM grade6 ORDER BY Number_006", con)
        con.Close()


     Dim dt as new DataTabe

    'Now I want to get da,da2,da3,da4,da5,da6 value  and fill it to datatable

    'example. da & da2 & da3 & da4 & da5 & da6.Fill(dt)

    'but you cant fill datatable with many data adapter..
    'is there a way to display multiple table in single DataGridView?
```

Comment: Sorry.. now I get it .. All I have to do is put a Space before UNION ALL.. Thannks a lot...

Answer (score 0):

How about running the sql all at once. Just put "union all" between each.
Here is an example of two tables joined:

```
"SELECT Number_001 as [Number],StudentID_001 as [Student Number], " & _
" LastName_001 as [Last Name],FirstName_001 as [First Name], " & _
" MiddleName_001 as [Middle Name], Address_001 as [Address], " & _
" Age_001 as [Age], Gender_001 as [Gender]" & _
" FROM grade1 ORDER BY Number_001" & _
" UNION ALL SELECT Number_002 as [Number],StudentID_002 as [Student Number], " & _
" LastName_002 as [Last Name],FirstName_002 as [First Name], " & _
" MiddleName_002 as [Middle Name], Address_002 as [Address], " & _
" Age_002 as [Age], Gender_002 as [Gender]" & _
" FROM grade2 ORDER BY Number_002"
```

Comment: {"Syntax error in query expression 'Number_001UNION ALL SELECT Number_002 as [Number]'."}

Comment: "SELECT Number_001 as [Number] FROM grade1 ORDER BY Number_001" & _
                                                "UNION ALL SELECT Number_002 as [Number] FROM grade2 ORDER BY Number_002"

Comment: sorry I missed a space when joining strings before UNION.  I will update my answer.

Comment: Sorry.. now I get it .. All I have to do is put a Space before UNION ALL.. Thannks a lot...